# Tomcat maxSavePostSize value?

Tags: linux, security, tomcat

Tomcat Error `403 the request body was too large to be cashed during authentication process`

Its related to maxSavePostSize setting its currently default which is 4096 (4KB). In googling people suggest  -1 (unrestricted). Does that means it could be subject of DOS attack? What you suggest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting maxSavePostSize to -1 on a Tomcat instance that is accessible by untrusted users would be a monumentally stupid thing to do because - as you correctly suspect - it would open up the server to a DoS attack.

This setting is only used when POST'd content needs to be saved during authentication. i.e. when an unauthenticated user POST's a request to a resource protected by FORM or CLIENT-CERT authentication.

There are a couple of solutions:
a) Structure your application in such a way that users are always authenticated before they are able to access pages that trigger POSTs
b) Increase the maxSavePostSize to the largest POST you expect you application to have to handle. If that is much larger than 4k then you may still be vulnerable to a DoS.

BTW, make sure you aren't confusing this setting with maxPostSize.

Comment: Thanks for reply. No i am not confused in maxPostSize. I guess increase size of maxSavePostSize would be easy solution rather than re-coding apps. What value you would suggest? 2MB?

Comment: 2MB is probably too high. The issue is that - for FORM auth - the data gets saved in the session which by default hangs around for 30 minutes. Far too easy to trigger an OOME and therefore a DOS. If you need that much data, I'd go for option a) rather than b)

Comment: i'd really appreciate some insight as to how to achieve option a)... some links perhaps?